# How to map predictions using INLA in R?

Tags: r, maps, prediction, shapefile

I'm having two problems:

1. Creating predictions from an INLA regression.
2. Mapping those predictions using a shapefile.

DATASET: (copied here from excel)

```
ID_1    NAME_1  x   y
1   Aceh    0.32    2.89
2   Bali    0.53    2.66
3   Bangka-Belitung 0.98    2.93
4   Banten  0.11    2.81
5   Bengkulu    0.73    3.06
```

PROBLEM 1: getting predictions.  My code is below (pieced together from various online resources and my shapefile for Indonesia).

```
rm(list=ls())

library(maptools)
library(spdep)
library(INLA)
library(lattice)

idn.gen <- readShapePoly("C:/Users/swulf/Desktop/IDN/maps/StatPlanet_Plus/Shapefile_map_(ESRI)/map/IDN province/IDN_adm1.shp", IDvar="ID_1")
idn.nb <- poly2nb(idn.gen)
nb2INLA("idn.graph", idn.nb)
#This create a file called ``LDN-INLA.adj'' with the graph for INLA
idn.adj <- paste(getwd(),"/idn.graph",sep="")


data <- read.csv("test for map.csv", header=TRUE)


g = system.file("demodata/idn.graph", package="INLA")
formula = y ~ f(ID_1,model="bym", graph.file=g) + x
# formula = y ~ f(ID_1,model="bym", graph=idn.adj) + x 
# (i'm not sure which formula syntax of graph file is preferred)
result = inla(formula, family="normal", data=data)

pred <- result$summary.random$ID$mean
```

The shapefile was downloaded from http://www.gadm.org/country for Indonesia, level adm1.  The "pred" is 66 rows long for some reason, but I'd expect 5 rows that correspond to my raw dataset.  Basically I want predictions for every ID_1.

Mapping is proving difficult for me too.  I've found different code to map, but haven't gotten any of them to work yet. Advice on which package is best would be helpful (maptools vs lattice vs something else).

Comment: That website looks like a valuable resource. Did you notice that one of the options was to download the boundary files as RSpatialDataframes?

Comment: Yes but I wasn't sure that there was any benefit to using that over a shapefile, and I'd rather get experience using shapefiles since they are more common for my work (global health).  Thanks for the suggestion though.